# Python input is requiring 3 lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, input, logic

Why is python requiring me to type input 3 times before telling me “you are not Alice!

```
print('What is your name')
input() #allows user to input their name
if input() == 'Alice':
    print('Hi, Alice. What is your age?')
age = input()
if age < 12:
    print('you are not Alice!')
elif age > 300:
    print ('unlike you, Alice isnt an undead, Immortal vampire')
```

Comment: How many times are you calling `input`? What are you doing with the data that it's giving you?

Comment: don't use `input()` multiple times, assign the first `input()` to a variable

Comment: python isn't requiring you to do anything here. You did that all on your own

Comment: `input() #allows user to input their name if input() == 'Alice':` You need to type in your name twice here, because you wanted user input twice.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion

Comment: Python is asking you for input 3 times because you used `input()` in your code 3 times. You should assign the first input to a variable and use the variable in replace of input

Comment: I don't think it's asking you *type input 3 times* that is not possible, as it would have failed before even getting into the first `if` scope. Please look into this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things, you have to assign the `input()` to a variable, it can't be done like you had it at run-time, and you have to make sure to indent the second `if/elif` to be *in-line* with the `age` input. Give this a try.

```
print('What is your name')
name = input() #allows user to input their name

if name == 'Alice':
   print('Hi, Alice. What is your age?')
   age = int(input())

   if age < 12:
     print('you are not Alice!')
   elif age > 300:
     print('unlike you, Alice isnt an undead, Immortal vampire')
```